# FileTrigger binding not parsing

Tags: azure, binding, azure-storage, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I have a file trigger pointing to a path to monitor files and I have set an appSetting value to use as a binding expressions:

```
[FileTrigger(@"%KEY_NAME%", "*", WatcherChangeTypes.Created, autoDelete: true)] string message,
```

I have an appSetting value to match it:

```
<add key="KEY_NAME" value="KEY_VALUE"/>
```

I have set the following:

```
    var filesConfig = new FilesConfiguration();
#if DEBUG
            filesConfig.RootPath = @"C:\Temp\data\";
#endif
            config.UseFiles(filesConfig);
```

so that I can hit a local folder. The directory does exist and is spelt the same and if I use the value directly it works. When I run the WebJob like this I get the following error:

```
    InvalidOperationException : Path 'C:\Temp\data\%KEY_VALUE%'
does not exist.
```

It appears that the concatenating of the RootPath prevents the parsing of the binding expression. What I would actually like to do is something like:

```
@"%VALUE_ONE%\%VALUE_TWO%\{name}"
```

so that I can make it work through our environments. Any advice available out there?

Comment: It could not achieve that. The path must be a const, so I suggest that you could create some function in the same webjobs.

Comment: Thats what I was afraid of. Thanks though.